# why don't move(js animation),help me

Tags: javascript

why don't move?

https://codepen.io/weblongzhao/full/oqLQoN

```
function move(){
  console.log(moveoffset+"out");
  while(moveoffset<offsetX){
    console.log(moveoffset+"moveoffsetWhileIn");
    $('.move').style.left=moveoffset+"px";
    setTimeout(function(){
          moveoffset++;
    },1000);
    console.log(offsetX+"offsetX");
  }
}
move()
```

Answer (score 1):

1.) Values of `moveoffset` and `offsetX` are not provided

2.) When using jQuery, `$('.move').css('prop', 'value')` is the right way

3.) In the `setTimeout` you are incrementing the `moveoffset` but you are not using this incremented value to update the `left` property